# How to programatically change a TextView to an ImageView and back

Tags: android, android-imageview, textview

I have an XML layout that defines a `TextView` box *50px x 320px* who ID is `TextView2`.
I want to use the same `TextView` area to show an image sometimes.
I want to programatically be able to switch that area to be either `TextView` or `ImageView`.

```
   <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.35"
        android:text="      "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add an ImageView below / next to your TextView and set the android:visibility="gone" on the one you don't want to show.

Also set an android:id="@+id/some_identifier" so that you can find the view in code and set the TextView to View.GONE and the ImageView to View.VISIBLE when you want to switch.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.35"
        android:text="      "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view_1"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Great! Thanks. I can use the same method to set an area to do multiple duties.  I know I could have used canvas. But good to see there is another way.

Answer (score 1):

Here you have two options :

1. You can set background of textview or set text whenever you want, based on certain conditions.
2. You can separatly take an ImageView nd when you want Image Set Visibility of imageView True and Textview GONE, Whereas When you want text then set Visibility of TextView True and ImageView GONE